# C - Choose random string from file

Tags: c, string, file, random, names

For homework, i am coding database of employees in C with some functions. I am nearly done and i have done some bonuses but i  would like to do one more. At beginning i generate random employees(using structs) but their names are only random "chars".

I would like to choose random name but i would like to avoid big array of names because i dont think its so good. I want use names.txt file with names and choose random name from this file. If you have any different idea of choosing random real name, you are welcome.

I am not posting code because i have problem only in this part of choosing name and i dont have anything in this small part right now.

I have tried something but only thing i can is print or save "chars" from this file but i need only specific random string.

Comment: Get a start on it and post back when you have specific problem with code you've written that we can help you with.

Comment: Do you know how many names are in the file? Pick a random number between 1 and the number of names, read that many names into the same variable. If you don't know the number of names, count them then go to beginning of this ;)

Comment: See Wikipedia on [Reservoir Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) — amongst other possibilities.  You only need to read the file once even if you don't know in advance how many lines are in it.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use txt file so you could edit it using text editor? If that is true you can format it manually to look something like:

Joe, 
Mike, 
George,

Now you can maybe find random number (between 0 and number of chars in file) and jump to that field of the file, then increase that number until it points to big letter. Then you simply read char by char, put it in an array, until you find comma indicating the name is over.

Also you could do it a bit simpler without any file - you could make array of names in code and read from there, only thing is you wouldn't have option to change it after compile.

I hope I understood your question and I was helpful, this is my first answer here :)